# JSTL request attribute in c:if

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I set a request attribute in my action class as follows:

```
request.setAttribute("xFg", Boolean.TRUE);
```

I want to retrive this in my JSP. I want to retrive them using JSTL tags. I tried this :

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.xFg}">
    <c:set var="showlist" value="true" />
</c:if>
```

But `c:if` didnt work, I mean it didn't go to `c:set`.
I tried to print the same using `c:out` but nothing got displayed. What is wrong or how should I test request attribute value? I haven't used `requestScope` so far. Is `requestScope` the option to get the request value?

Comment: try this `test="${requestScope['xFg']}"`

Comment: What happens when you do `<c:out value="${requestScope}"/>`?

Comment: Check that the JSTL core library is declared at the top of your JSP. Check the generated HTML code, and se if you don't have unprocessed c:if and c:set tag inside.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to activate EL evaluation in your JSP page by specifying the attribute isELIgnored=”false” in the page directive as follows:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```